# MYSQL Query: 3 Table UNION, Last 100 Results in ASC Order

Tags: php, mysql

So far, I have taken 3 tables and joined them together. What I want to do is display the Last 100 entries (DESC) in ASC ORDER according to the timestamp in the column  Posted.

This is as far as I could get: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e2771/1

In addition, if there is a more efficient way to do this in PhP and not MYSQL, I'm all for that. I've tried looking, but haven't been able to find anything that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need one more level of sort:

```
select t.*
from (<your query here>) t
order by posted;
```